# postgresql complex group by in query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a **query** that gives:

```
itemid deadlineneeded delievrydate quantity 
200  15/07/15        14/07/15     5     
200  15/07/15        14/07/15     10
200  15/07/15        13/07/15     25
201  15/07/15        14/07/15     30
200  14/07/15        10/07/15     3
201  15/07/15        15/07/15     100
```

It gives the information from multiple tables. Basically it means When items arrive to warehouse (delievrydate) and how many. The deadlineneeded means when i'm going to use it.

My goal is to find out the total quantity of itemid that arrives 1 day before deadlineeded.

for example with the last data I want to get:

```
itemid deadlineneeded    quantity
200         15/07/15      43 (5+10+25+3)  
200         14/07/15      3    //5+10+25 not included because deliverydate
201         15/07/15     30    //100 not included because deliverydate
```

How do i get it?

Comment: Use GROUP BY combined with SUM.

Comment: I tried. it gives false results... to solve it I must take under considration the delievrydate and it is something that changes for each row... it's not a simple sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT itemid, deadlineneeded, sum(quantity) AS total_quantity
FROM <your table>
WHERE (deadlineneeded - delievrydate)::int >= 1
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

This uses a "delievrydate" (looks like a typo to me) that is *at least* 1 day before the "deadlineneeded" date, as your sample data is suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct date_trunc('day',deadlineneeded),sum from 
(select *,sum(quantity) over (partition by deadlineneeded-delievrydate) from     tablename) t 
where deadlineneeded-delievrydate = '1 day';
```

Comment: you won't see itemid, cos you summarize the quantity... you can list them though comma though...

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` combined with aggregate function `SUM`.

```
select itemid, deadlineneeded, SUM(quantity)
from tablename
where deadlineneeded = delievrydate + 1
group by itemid, deadlineneeded
```

The `where deadlineneeded = delievrydate + 1` part is typically product specific, and I don't know postgresql... ANSI SQL has `deadlineneeded = delievrydate + interval'1' day`.